# How exactly does "intel_iommu=igfx_off" affect the passthrough of an Intel IGD?

Tags: gpu, hardware, intel, acceleration, iommu

How exactly does "intel_iommu=igfx_off" affect the passthrough of an Intel IGD? Does it prevent the detachment of Intel IGD from host altogether so that the emulator such as qemu-kvm won't even see the assigned GPU in the first place as one of the available graphic device, let alone guest which is yet to boot? Or does it just affect graphics hardware acceleration to be unavailable within guest?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have issues with moderator actions, either use the *Contact us* link at the bottom of the page (which will go to the Community Manager team, employees of Stack Overflow), or post on [meta] (requires 5 points or more, and addresses the community). Either way, bring your point *politely* and with all context.